# Is "regular" a technical term for a grammar?

Tags: terminology

Reading the [Go language specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec), I read in the intro:

"The grammar is compact and regular, allowing for easy analysis by automatic tools such as integrated development environments."

Is the word "regular" here a technical term, or should it be interpreted just as a vague English word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a technical term, but not *the* technical term you are thinking of.

In this case, "regular" means composed of few rules with with few corner cases.

The term for a grammar that describes a regular *language* is usually *left-linear* or *right-linear*, "regular grammar" in *this* sense is rather uncommon. A compact notation for describing regular languages are regular *expressions*.

Go's grammar is not in CH-3, i.e. not regular in that sense of the word, but it has a lot less corner cases than, say, Java, C#, C++ or C, so it is a lot more regular (in the other sense) than those.

Answer (score 2):

"Regular" is a technical term for grammars, but I strongly doubt it is used with that meaning here as a regular grammar can describe only regular languages, which may also be described by regular expressions.